# Why does the definition of orthogonality use a weighting function?

Tags: integration, orthogonality

I've been reading about the Fourier series and was looking over the [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalFunctions.html) page on orthogonality, which provides this definition:

> Two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are orthogonal over the interval $a\leq x\leq b$ with [weighting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeightingFunction.html) $w(x)$ if
>
> $$\left<\,f\left(x\right)|\,g\left(x\right)\right>\equiv \int_a^bf\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)w\left(x\right)\,dx=0.$$

Why is a weighting function used here? Surely $\int_a^bf\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\,dx$ has to equal $0$ on its own for the two functions to be considered orthogonal.

Comment: The definition of "orthogonal" used an inner product.  Some examples of inner products are the ones with weight $w$ that you cite.  There are in fact other examples of inner products not of that form.  Each inner product gives you its own concept of "orthogonal".

Comment: @GEdgar what are some other definitions of orthogonal?

Comment: According to what I said, you should ask "what are some other example of inner products?"  Then you could easily find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: Is it correct for me to say "$f$ and $g$ are orthogonal over the interval $a<x<b$ if $\int_a^b f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\,dx=0$?

Comment: It is better to say: I will use the inner product $\int_a^b f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = \sum a_i e_i(x)$ and the $e_i(x)$ are orthonormal, within the appropriate restrictions, then, for all $i$, $a_i = \langle f, e_i \rangle$.

In that sense, weighting functions allow you to more fully abstract the concept of orthogonality, making it possible to exploit the above property more often.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the weighting function? Wolfram says $\int f_n(x)^2w(x)dx=N_n$ but I don't know what $N_n$ is.

Comment: Is it correct for me to say "$f$ and $g$ are orthogonal over the interval $a<x<b$ if $\int_a^b f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\,dx=0$?

Comment: Yes, but it may not be useful for you to say that. See for example Wikipedia's article about [Orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

Why? For each weighting function we have a different inner product. For instance, if you are studying periodic functions whose period is $2\pi$, it is natural to define $w(x)=\frac1{2\pi}$; in other words,$$\bigl\langle f(x),g(x)\bigr\rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$And in other contexts it may be appropriate to use non-constant functions as weighting functions.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely $\int_a^b f(x) \, g(x) \, dx$ has to equal $0$ on its own for the two functions to be considered orthogonal.

This is not true.

Take $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$, and $g(x) = +1$ for $x>0$ and $g(x)
 = -1$ for $x<0$. Then
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \, g(x) \, dx = 0$$
but for $w(x) = 1$ for $x<0$ and $w(x) = 2$ for $x>0$ we get
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \, g(x) \, w(x) dx = 1$$
so the functions are not orthogonal when we have this weight.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the weighting function? Wolfram says $\int f_n(x)^2w(x)dx=N_n$ but I don't know what $N_n$ is.

Comment: @theonlygusti - $N_n$ is a positive real number whose value depends on $n$. Its actual value depends on $w(x)$  See [orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) for example.

Comment: Is it correct for me to say "$f$ and $g$ are orthogonal over the interval $a<x<b$ if $\int_a^b f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\,dx=0$?

Comment: The weighting function must be positive.

Comment: Whether $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal depends on the chosen inner product, and that depends on the weight function:
$$\langle f, g \rangle_w := \int f(x) \, g(x) \, w(x) dx$$
Different choices of $w$ give different inner products and different criteria for orthogonality.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of orthogonality makes sense only if you specify to which scalar product it refers. In the definiton you quoted the scalar product is:
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x)w(x)dx $$
So the definition of orthogonality is:
$$0 = \langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x)w(x)dx$$.

Answer (score 0):

But why include the weight function in the definition if it's basically extraneous? That would just be extra words for no gain.
There must be an actual application of an inner product with such a non-constant weight function, right?

One need look no farther than theory, in fact.
The best reason I've found for this particular definition is that by suitable choices in weight function, all the classical orthogonal polynomials are subsumed under one definition, that is, Jacobi, Hermite, Laguerre, and indeed even more types.

Answer (score 0):

One could summarize the above response to the 'why' question as 'because we can' in the sense that it doesn't affect the relevant theorems that make use of inner products.  This is true but somewhat un-satisfying as it doesn't give us any clue as to the role that that the weight function plays or why one would choose one weight function over another.

It is my view that the weight function is present to remind us that the geometry of a function space is coordinate system dependent.  Consider the inner product

$\left<f(x),g(x)\right> = \int f(x)g(x)dx$

Now change the coordinate system:  $x=W(u)$.  Since this is a coordinate system change $W(u)$ should be smooth and uniquely invertible.  We will make that happen by requiring that it is monotonically increasing, so that $dx = w(u)du$ with $w(u)>0$ for all $u$.  Clearly,

$\left<f(x),g(x)\right> = \left<f(u),g(u)\right>_{w(u)} = \int f(u)g(u)w(u)du$

This trivial result makes it clear that the role of the weight function is to specify the mapping from the coordinate system in which you are working ($u$) to Euclidean coordinates ($x$) where the inner product is more naturally defined.